# How to change the header in memoir

Tags: fonts, formatting

How can I do the following in **page headers** in memoir (without changing anything else):

- remove "Chapter" (and the chapter number) from page titles. (So only chapter title remains).
- Make the title and page number boldface with sans serif font.
- change the font size (exclusively the header) to 12 pt.
- All other things (including the line etc.) unchanged.

I really searched a lot both in the site and memoir but couldn't make it.

Comment: Sorry daleif! You were right, there is a fancyhdr package in the background that I was not aware of... Thank you for your answer anyway!

Comment: solved by using `fancyhdr` package!

Comment: See the importance of providing the MWE. Memoir has a much more integrated system for headers than what is provided by `fancyhdr`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.